# Which objective tests have been developed to test the intelligence of AI?

Tags: intelligence-testing

Which objective and measurable tests have been developed to test the intelligence of AI?

The classical test is the Turing Test, which has objective criteria and is measurable since it can be measured what percentage of the jury is fooled by the AI.

I am looking for other, more modern tests.

Comment: I voted to close this question since there are many different possible ways to develop tests with objective criteria and measurability, and it'd be hard to mention them all exhaustively. I would recommend reading this article about [a proposed plan to replace the Turing Test with an "Olympics"](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/the-plan-to-replace-the-turing-test-with-a-turing-olympics) and this blog post about [the Lovelace Tests](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/turing-test-computer-intelligence-too-easy-test-would-look-computer-creativity-180953640/?no-ist)...

Comment: ...for a good sense of how such 'objective' and measurable tests are designed in the modern day. But just because these tests can be objective doesn't mean that the results can be valid or useful to have. After all, even the Turing Test itself can be arguably beaten, which is why we have proposals for alternatives to the Turing Test.

Answer (score 0):

Winograd Schema Challenge

ImageNet Classification Challenge

General Video Game AI (GVGAI) Competition

RoboCup Soccer

Stanford Question Answering Dataset (SQuAD)

VQA (Visual Question Answering) Challenge

Comment: This could do with some background discussion, and clarification that these are more narrow targetted AI tests compared to the Turing Test - some narrower than others. A brief description of each one would be good, too, and/or a link to the official sites for the tests